# Twitter API JSON - wrong IDs of the tweets

Tags: javascript, api, twitter

I'm trying to display my last tweets with the twitter api on my website.
I've included the following function (I use jQuery):

```
function render(o) {
  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    $('.section').append('<a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/mytwittername/status/' + o[i].id + '">' + o[i].text + '</a><br /><hr /><br />');
  }
}
```

After that I include the json file with the callback:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/mytwittername?
callback=render"></script>
```

It all works kinda fine. The content of the tweets is correct. But the ID isn't. The ID is correct, except the last digit is always a 0, but actually it is another number. In the source code of the json file the ID is the right one.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to parse out id_str attribute instead. JS doesn't support 64bit numbers as far as I know. So Twitter returns string representation.

Details here: http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-api-announce/browse_thread/thread/6a16efa375532182?pli=1 or there http://hustoknow.blogspot.com/2011/02/twitters-idstr.html

Comment: Thanks! That was the solution.

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer as a solution if it works for you )

Comment: I did now. I had to wait 3 more minutes to do it. :P